# Constructor call to proxy of a bound function

Tags: javascript, node.js, constructor, prototype, proxy-pattern

Suppose I have a function `Foo`, and I want objects constructed from it to have a `bar` property:

```
function Foo() {}
Foo.prototype.bar = 'baz'
console.log('new Foo().bar: ' + new Foo().bar)
```

---

```
new Foo().bar: baz
```

Now suppose I [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) `Foo` in some way. Bound functions can still be used in constructor calls, and the bound `this` is ignored:

```
const Bound = Foo.bind(42)
console.log('new Bound().bar: ' + new Bound().bar)
```

---

```
new Bound().bar: baz
```

[Proxies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) are supposed to be general and transparent. However...

```
const PFoo = new Proxy(Foo, { })
console.log('new PFoo().bar: ' + new PFoo().bar)

const PBound = new Proxy(Bound, { })
console.log('new PBound().bar: ' + new PBound().bar)
```

---

```
new PFoo().bar: baz
new PBound().bar: undefined
```

I would expect the second proxy to behave exactly as `Bound`, since I am using an empty handler. In other words, I would expect the last output to be `baz`.

Why is it not the case?

(complete snippet follows)

```js
function Foo() {}
Foo.prototype.bar = 'baz'
console.log('new Foo().bar: ' + new Foo().bar)

const Bound = Foo.bind(42)
console.log('new Bound().bar: ' + new Bound().bar)

const PFoo = new Proxy(Foo, { })
console.log('new PFoo().bar: ' + new PFoo().bar)

const PBound = new Proxy(Bound, { })
console.log('new PBound().bar: ' + new PBound().bar)
```

Comment: (OT: is it possible to interleave text and code in executable snippets?)

Comment: I don't think so, but you can use comments. (Or you can post multiple snippets)

Comment: Bound functions don't have their own `.prototype` object but they appear to search for it from their origin when `new` is used, while proxied functions only provide it if the original has it directly. So there must be some difference in how the `.prototype` is requested. The spec will have the answer if anyone cares to check.

Comment: @rockstar I was aware of the missing `prototype` from bound function, but never heard/thought of the proxied function only providing it if the proxied function has it directly. Will check, thanks for the input.

Comment: Putting `console.log("new.target:", new.target.name);` in the `Foo` constructor yields an interesting result.

Comment: @rockstar Focusing on `new.target` was correct, thanks. I think I got it, I will write an answer with some details from the spec. Not sure this is actually a feature though...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## tl;dr

When using `new F`, `new.target` is set to `F` *unless* `F` is a bound function, in that case `new.target` becomes the original function. This does not happen with proxies.

## Long answer

Ok, I think I got it. [This comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47892716/constructor-call-to-proxy-of-a-bound-function#comment82753310_47892716) was a good starting point. Key ingredients:

- [`new.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new.target)
- [[Prototype]] internal slot
- constructor functions `prototype` property

Note: in constructor calls, the new object's prototype is set to `new.target.prototype`. This is step 5 from [this specification](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-ecmascript-function-objects-construct-argumentslist-newtarget).

Starting point: when doing `new F()`, [`new.target` is initially set to `F`](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-new-operator) (follow links). However, this can change during the process of construction...

### `new Foo()`

Nothing weird here, `new.target` is `Foo` and the newly created object prototype is `Foo.prototype`.

### `new Bound()`

This is interesting. At the beginning, `new.target` is `Bound`. However, step 5 of [bound functions [[Construct]] internal method](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-bound-function-exotic-objects-construct-argumentslist-newtarget) does the following: if `new.target` is set to the bound function, then it is changed to the target function, which is `Foo`. Thus, `Foo.prototype` is used again.

### `new PFoo()`

`new.target` is always `PFoo`, but it is a proxy for `Foo`, so when `PFoo.prototype` is requested `Foo.prototype` is given, again.

### `new PBound()`

`new.target` is set to `PBound`. This time, when the [[Construct]] internal method of the bound function is called, `new.target` is *not* equal to the bound function, so it is not changed, and we end up using `PBound.prototype`, which is forwarding to `Bound.prototype`. Indeed...

```js
function Foo() { }
Foo.prototype.iAm = 'Foo'
const Bound = Foo.bind(42)
Bound.prototype = {iAm: 'Bound'}
const Proxied = new Proxy(Bound, { })
console.log(new Proxied().iAm)
```

Personal opinion: I understand that, when constructing a bound function, `new.target` is changed so that everything works as expected. Similarly, I would expect the construction of proxy objects to set `new.target` to the proxied function before going on. This is a naive thought, and maybe there are corner cases I am not considering.

Comment: Nice. I do wonder why they made that decision, or if it was an oversight. The fact that they do let you call `new` on a Proxy instance sure would seem to suggest that they intend for the wrapped function to be used as expected. Maybe the esdiscuss list has some info on this.

Comment: @rockstar I couldn't find anything... guess I will create an issue in the working group's GitHub repo, it looks like a good place for it.

Comment: @rockstar done https://github.com/tc39/ecma262/issues/1052 (sorry for notification, thought you may be interested in it)

Comment: Awesome. I was just about to leave a comment asking for a link. :-)